# Using Templates on a SP 2010 Library

Tags: site-template, form-library

I've been sent three templates which are lists of Locations and Departments. I've uploaded them to the site via the Site Settings. Now how can I use these in the Form Library? I presume it's a setting in Columns so I can use the lists?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm also using an InfoPath form.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out what to do! Basically upload the templates into the List Library, create a List from the template then create a lockup column in the library/or do in the InfoPath form right click the relevant field and pick 'Get choices from an external data source and Bob's your uncle!